# Simple MEF example in C++ / CLI

Tags: c++, mef, command-line-interface

Anybody can give simple MEF example in C++/CLI?

Best Wishes

PS:I try to convert C# examples but have diffuculties...For example

```
CompositionBatch^ batch = gcnew CompositionBatch();
batch->AddPart(this);
```

In C++/CLI i can not reach `CompositionBatch` class overloaded method `AddPart(object attributedPart)` of `CompositionBatch`...Compiler just see `AddPart(ComposablePart part)` method...In fact i downloaded the latest source of MEF(in C#),in can not find any method signature with `AddPart(object attributedPart)` but Intellisense show me as an extension in a C# project which confuse me more...

Comment: This has nothing to do with MEF.  You're trying to call an extension method using C++.  You should remove the mef tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++/CLI doesn't support extension methods this way.  Extension methods are resolved by the compiler into absolute method calls.  That particular method is an extension method of the `AttributedModelServices` class.  Call it as such:

```
AttributedModelServices::AddPart(batch, this);
```